# Is there a way to redirect a file without using its extension in Unix?

Tags: c, unix

For example I have a C program with executable target *prog* and a file *file.txt*

Is there a way in my C program to make stdin to read and accept the file.txt without its extension.  Currently my code to read the stdin is..

```
while (scanf("%d ", &n) != EOF)
```

For this I would have to do ./prog < file.txt

But I want to do this ./prog < file

Comment: Is renaming `file.txt` to `file` an option?

Comment: no. because it's not C doing the parsing of the filename. the redirection occurs at the shell level. you're pretty much telling the shell "take `file` and turn it into prog's stdin". That means you COULD do `prog < file*`

Comment: Have you tried it? That would have been much faster than posting here. What happened?

Comment: That's what I thought the redirection is the shell not my C prog.

Comment: `ln file.txt file`

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to do this ./prog < file

No, that won't work. You'll just have to be explicit and use:

```
./prog < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your program so that instead of redirecting using the OS, you take the file as a command line argument and open+read it yourself.

That way you can do whatever string manipulation on the file name you think is necessary.

Comment: yeah that was one of our objective too.  I did that easily but in his direction it seem like he wanted the redirection to use the file with implicit extension as well